# For loop in listview

Tags: android, arrays, listview, for-loop

I have a ListView that uses a custom adapter. Each row contains 2 CheckBoxes that I want to check if they are ticked.

How would I loop through each row to check this and then, if they are checked, change a boolean array at the row position to true, then save these arrays using SharedPreferences?

And how would I set each CheckBox after opening the activity again by looking if the array at the position is true or false?
Thanks.

ListAdapter

```
public class LockerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<LockerData> {

private Context mContext;
private int mLayoutResourceId;
LockerData[] mData = null;
CheckBox checkBoxHwk;
CheckBox checkBoxLkr;

//trying to change these arrays if boxes are ticked
public boolean[] homeworkCheck = new boolean[6];
public boolean[] lockerCheck = new boolean[6];

public LockerAdapter(Context context, int resource, LockerData[] objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mLayoutResourceId = resource;
    this.mData = objects;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    LockerHolder holder = null;

    if(row == null){

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        row = inflater.inflate(mLayoutResourceId,parent,false);
        holder = new LockerHolder();

        holder.theLessonName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.generalLessonName);
        holder.hwkCheck = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.homeworkCheck);
        holder.lkrCheck = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.lockerCheck);

        row.setTag(holder);
    }else {
        holder = (LockerHolder) row.getTag();
    }
    LockerData lesson = mData[position];
    holder.theLessonName.setText(lesson.lessonsName);

    return row;

}

public class LockerHolder{
    TextView theLessonName;
    CheckBox hwkCheck;
    CheckBox lkrCheck;
}
```

}

Activity

```
public class HomeworkLockerActivity extends Activity {

private ListView hwkListview;
private LockerAdapter lockerAdapter;
private CheckBox checkBoxChem;
private CheckBox checkBoxPhys;
private CheckBox checkBoxMech;
private CheckBox checkBoxFP;
private CheckBox checkBoxCore;
private CheckBox checkBoxStats;

/*LockerData is just a class that takes in a single string in the
constructor to store the data*/
public LockerData[] lessons = {
        new LockerData("Chemistry"),
        new LockerData("Physics"),
        new LockerData("Mechanics"),
        new LockerData("Further Pure"),
        new LockerData("Core 1"),
        new LockerData("Statistics"),
};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_homework_locker);

    hwkListview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.homeworkListview);
    lockerAdapter = new LockerAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.list,lessons);
    hwkListview.setAdapter(lockerAdapter);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I recommend editing your LockerData class to accept three inputs: the name (ex: Chemistry), whether the homework is checked, and whether the locker is checked. Then you could edit your getView() in your adapter to case over the boolean values within the LockerData class instance, updating your checkboxes accordingly. With this approach, your two lists homeworkCheck and lockerCheck are not necessary.

As for Shared Preferences, I believe that you can only store primitive values (ex: boolean, int, string, etc.) and not lists. I would use an onCheckChanged Listener to update your shared preferences every time a checkbox is updated; so something like:

```
holder.hwkCheck.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
       @Override
       public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
         SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
         //check what kind of button this is, in this case its chemistry
         editor.putBoolean("chemistryCheck", isChecked);
       }
   }
);
```

I would retrieve these shared preferences in your Activity's onCreate class, and initialize your LockerData[] lessons accordingly.